# How to sign Windows 10 (UWP) App?

Tags: cordova, certificate, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

The process should be the same, like for Windows 8.1(Universal) Apps. ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt269549.aspx))

I used this command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\BuildMDILAPPX.ps1" -appxfilename "C:\SignApps\App.appx" -pfxfilename "c:\SignApps\Certificate.pfx" -password ***** -inputFolder "C:\SignApps\input" -outputfolder "C:\SignApps\output"
```

The signing process throw this error:

```
MakeAppx : error: You must include a valid app package manifest file named AppxManifest.xml in the source.
MakeAppx : error: Package creation failed.
MakeAppx : error: 0x80080203 - The specified package format is not valid: The file is not a valid app package because it is missing a required footprint file.
```

The apps are build through cordova. When i use the Windows 8.1 Universal App, the signing works. Using the Windows 10, it fails. The app will be provided over a mdm (where the AET is already added).

How do i sign correctly?

### Environment

OS: *Windows 8.1 Enterprise*

IDEs installed: *Visual Studio Community 2013 & 2015*

IDE used: *Visual Studio Community 2015*

VS Project details: *Apache Cordova, WinJS, angularjs*

Certificate: *Company certificate from symantec, received from extern company*

Comment: Hi! have you found a solution by now? Having the same issue here, except without Cordova.

Comment: Struggling too, complete lack of (clear) documentation for this. I have a similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292356/error-0x80080209-when-signing-appx-file-for-windows-uwp). So frustrating. For iOS and Android is it clear what to do, but not for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command : 
**signtool sign /fd <HashAlgorithm> /a /f c:\SignApps\Certificate.pfx /p  <Your pfx password> App.appx**

So, your original app will be signed.

Note : **Signtool** is installed by installing Windows SDK 10 and added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64" this path in environment variable. 
You'll get your app HashAlgorithm by this method :

- Rename your app to .zip then extract this file AppxBlockMap.xml
- Now search for the following : HashMethod=
  "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#
- After xmlenc# there will be your
  hash algorithm for example in mine case :
  HashMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" it is **sha256**