# Error 0x80080209 when signing appx file for Windows UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10, code-signing, visual-studio-cordova, signtool

I have build a Windows 10 UWP cordova application, and are now trying to sign it. I already have a certificate that is used elsewhere (to sign .net assemblies) so I thought I would use the same one for this application signing.

When I use the signtool.exe, I get the following error..

```
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146958839/0x80080209)
```

Looking in the event log as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx), I see no errors just 2 information messages

*The reader was created successfully without manifest validation.*

I have made sure the `Publisher` fields in the AppxManifest.xml file matches the subject in the certificate.

Looking [here](http://techmeonline.com/windows-store-apps-common-error-codes/), I see this described as

```
0x80080209-APPX_E_INVALID_SIP_CLIENT_DATA
Description : The SIP_SUBJECTINFOstructure used to sign the package didn’t 
contain the required data
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means?

**[UPDATE1]**

After the above failed, I attempted to create a new certificate as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing).

I used the following.

```
# create
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=My Company Pty Ltd, O=My Company Pty Ltd, C=AU" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName mycert_uwp -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"

 # get info
 Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
 Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject, FriendlyName, Thumbprint

 # export
 $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String password123 -Force -AsPlainText 
 Export-PfxCertificate -cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\17BBBBBB2DC49F550671AF3E72120C88E2333333" -FilePath h:\0\mycert_uwp.pfx -Password $pwd
```

All appeared to work fine.

In my AppxManifest.xml I have...

```
<Identity Name="com.mycompany.myapp" Publisher="CN=My Company Pty Ltd, O=MyCompany Pty Ltd, C=AU" Version="1.0.1.1" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" />
```

I still get the same error when using the above.

**[UPDATE 2]**

The signtool command I am using is

```
signtool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f myapp_uwp.pfx /p may password c:\dev\myapp\platforms\windows\build\windows\release\x86\win10\Upload\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.1.1_x86\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.1.1_x86.appx
```

as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

I have also tried using `SHA384` and `SHA512`. There is also the suggestions to try using the `/debug` and I get an error suggesting `/debug` is an invalid option.

**[UPDATE3]**
It appears to be the certificate. I tried to use via Visual Studio (Packaging, Choose certificate), but get the following error (after entering the password)

[image]

.. and yets I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing) (and triple checked).

Are these instructions wrong??

Comment: Can you include your manifest and the cert info in your question? And did you create your certificate following [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx) -- in particular the two EKUs?

Comment: I had seen the link above. This has the link labelled `Important  MakeCert.exe is deprecated. For current guidance on creating a certificate, see Create a certificate for package signing.` so I followed the instructions from there. Ive added the extra info to the question.

Comment: Try following the instructions in [this article](http://aka.ms/mrtforcentennial). Ignore all the resources bits but it does have explicit instructions for creating a cert etc.

Comment: Also see this [batch file](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SigningCerts)

Comment: Thanks for that extra info. Looking at the first link, the signing step `signtool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f ..\contoso_demo_key.pfx ..\contoso_demo.appx` is exactly what I have been runnning. The actual building and packaging is done via the Ionic build, so perhaps something in the build is different that makes the certificates not work. I also tried the batch in the second link. The certificate is created fine, but now the signtool complains wrong password, even though I definitely use the same password (as very simple 2 character one that I tried many times over to make sure no typos)

Comment: Can you try building manually with makeappx?

Comment: I could try using the makeappx. Also, I tried importing the certificate made by the sample bat file into Visual Studio, and it accepted it! I then built (using VS), and this succeeded, but then when I took the file CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.1.1_x86.appx` and double clicked to install , it reports `Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or you need a new app package with trusted certificates. Your system administrator or the app developer can help. A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which isn’t trusted (0x800B0109).`

Comment: Good, that's progress. The doc also tells you how to trust the cert.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else had similar issue (0x80080209 error while signing), newer version of signing tool (the one from Windows 10 SDK) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:
`Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146958839/0x80080209)`

But had no log entries, and the manifest was correct.

Our fix was to compile with msvc2017, not msvc2015.